# Linq groupby IdCordinator only if categery type count greater than one

Tags: linq, count, group-by, where-clause

Need to group records by IdCordinator, 
Conditions

1. If category type not equal "S", include in group
2. If category type is "S" **for a particular coordinator and count is greater than** 1 include in group
3. If category type is "S" for **a particular coordinator and count is equal to 1 do not include in group**

How should i frame my where clause. If i have a where clause as below, if there is only one element is list though it is not of category "S" it returns 0 records.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace LinqGroupbyWhere
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            StudentList studentList = new StudentList();
            studentList.getList();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class StudentList
    {
        public void getList()
        {

            List<Students> stdLst = new List<Students>();
            stdLst.Add( new Students( "stud1", 20, "M", "I001" ) );
            stdLst.Add( new Students( "stud2", 20, "M", "I001" ) );
            stdLst.Add( new Students( "stud3", 20, "M", "I002" ) );
            stdLst.Add( new Students( "stud4", 20, "M", "I003" ) );
            stdLst.Add( new Students( "stud5", 20, "S", "I001" ) );
            stdLst.Add( new Students( "stud6", 20, "S", "I001" ) );
            stdLst.Add( new Students( "stud7", 20, "S", "I002" ) );

            var lst = stdLst.GroupBy( s => s.IdCordinator )
         .SelectMany( sg =>
                sg.Where( s => !s.Category.Equals( "S" ) || sg.Count( c => c.Category.Equals( "S" ) ) > 1 )
               .Select( student => student.Name ) )
               .OrderBy( o => o );

            Console.WriteLine( string.Join( ",", (string[]) lst.ToArray() ) );


        }
    }
    public class Students
    {

        public Students( string name, int age, string cat, string siCordinator )
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Age = age;
            this.Category = cat;
            this.IdCordinator = siCordinator;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Category
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string IdCordinator
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to get as output result of query, can you please be more clear

Comment: The output should be
List<string> stNames = ["stud1","stud2","stud3","stud4","stud5"]

Here "stud6" should be there as in category "S" under IdCordinator group its just one record

PS: I have updated the code to show the proper student names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this to get the output as you want :

```
var lst = stdLst.GroupBy(s => s.IdCordinator)
         .SelectMany(sg =>
                sg.Where(s => !s.Category.Equals("S") || sg.Count(c => c.Category.Equals("S")) > 1)
               .Select(student => student.Name))
               .OrderBy(o => o);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Update your constructor like this :

```
public Students( string name, int age, string cat, string siCordinator )
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Age = age;
    this.Category = cat;
    this.IdCordinator = siCordinator; // You were assiging same field to itself here, making it null
}
```

Comment: No still the output is stud1,stud2,stud3,stud4,stud5,stud6,stud7... Console.WriteLine( string.Join( ",", (string[]) lst.ToArray() ) );. Where stud7 should not come

Comment: @kvk95, look back to your question again, what you have asked, you are grouping the records by 'IdCordinator' property and your condition 2. "If category type is "S" for a particular coordinator and count is greater than 1 include in group". So your Stud7 is in "I002" group for which count is 2 which is greater then 1 so it is obviously included. please don't make contradictory statements. Make yourself sure what you want.

Comment: I am not making any condradictory statement it says for particular co ordinator & S belongs to Coordinator "I002" in which case there is only one "S" present. If the question is not clear i am extremly sorry.

Comment: @kvk95, what I am getting is, you are grouping by IdCordinator and your I002  group has 2 students stud3 and stud7 so it is included, if your group would have only 1 student and with "S" category, it will not be included. That's what I did.

Comment: Please look in the code now, I have updated it. I think this is what you want finally. The more the question is clear, the faster you get the help. :)

Comment: Mark sorry for late reply. Net access is a problem in my machine, but still i get the same result **sg.Count( c => c.Category.Equals( "S" ) ) > 1** this condition always returns all the records. Result _stud1,stud2,stud3,stud4,stud5,stud6,stud7_

Comment: what?? I have same code on my machine and it is working correctly man, filtering the records same as you required

Comment: Mark i think you are still not clear with the question, stud 7 should not come as there is only one "S", **if there is only one "S"** under a idcoordinator, even though there is **some other category for the same coordinator**. _If my english is not clear i am sorry_

Comment: can you please post your Students constructor code again??

Comment: How foolish man..!!! can you see in you constructor, what you are doing.. "this.IdCordinator = IdCordinator;" while you are passing value as "siCordinator", so it will always return null, and there will no grouping occure. I had already updated your question code, still you didn't change. This is working solution and still you are denying.

Comment: Look at asnwer again, and update your constructor that way, It will solve your problem, and you will get desired result

Comment: Thanxs a lot what a mistake (because of intellisense), taken a lot of time. It works like charm